# How can I shoot a 60fps video?

Tags: root-access, xiaomi

I have xiaomi redmi 5 plus/Note 5 that have the option to record 1080p60fps but actually the result would be 30fps .. So i have rooted and enabled camera2 api .. But I still have the same result even with google camera .. So I want to record with at least 720p60fps .. Any help ??

Comment: Try using magisk manager to get HEVC 60fps encoding module

Comment: Can you give me a name for a module ?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Disclaimer: Haven't tried out this proceedure since my device is not current supported.</sup>

Requirements:

- Magisk (or TWRP)
- [MIUIcamerav2_whyred (magisk module)](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/MIUIcamerav2_whyred/blob/master/make/test/MiCamV2_whyred_v1.0.3d.zip)

Since you have a rooted device I'm assuming you have magisk installed already, if not then install it, as it will make the work easier.

- Basically you need to download the module MIUI Camerav2 port (from Mi A2 series) and flash it in recovery/via magisk manager.

> <sup>Notes: For  MIUI based ROM, the packages are a simpler version
>   because there is no need to install another camera, stock one is
>   already MIUI Camera v2. The mod just enables **more functions in the
>   stock app** (you can see from the function list what is enabled and
>   what is stock). Depending on the MIUI version there are more function
>   like
>   **60fps** available.</sup>

*If camera don't start check permission, try to clear app data (it will reset permission too). 
If still not working wipe cache and dalwik from TWRP.*

Comment: Working on Oreo and Pie

Comment: It looks like my phone isn't supported :(

Comment: "This module is for whyred only, sorry"

Comment: Is there any other solution or module for vince ?